# Second order correction to $ {\epsilon} +{\epsilon^{1/2}}+{\epsilon^{1/3}}+\dots+{\epsilon^{1/(-b\ln \epsilon)}}$?

Tags: asymptotics, solution-verification

### Background

I recently asked myself the following where $\epsilon > 0$ and $b > 0$

$$ {\epsilon} +{\epsilon^{1/2}}+{\epsilon^{1/3}}+\dots+{\epsilon^{1/(-b\ln \epsilon)}} = ?$$

After some fiddling around I was able to show:

$$ {\epsilon} +{\epsilon^{1/2}}+{\epsilon^{1/3}}+\dots+{\epsilon^{1/(-b\ln \epsilon)}} \sim - \ln(\epsilon) \times \int_0^{b} e^{-1/|x|} dx$$

### Question

Is my fiddling correct? I suspect there is an $(\ln \epsilon)^2$ term as well but I cannot find it. Any help?

### My Fiddling

Consider:

$$ f(x) = e^{-1/x} $$

Now,

$$ \int_0^b f(x) dx = \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n \delta) \delta $$

with $N = \frac{b}{\delta}$ and $\delta> 0$. Let us replace $\delta =\frac{-1}{\ln(\epsilon)}$

$$ \int_0^b f(x) dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{N} f\left(\frac{-1}{\ln ( \epsilon^{1/n})} \right) \frac{-1}{\ln \epsilon} $$

with $N=-b \ln(\epsilon)$. Substituting $f(x)$:

$$\int_0^b  e^{-1/x} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \epsilon^{1/n} \frac{1}{\ln \epsilon} $$

Using asymptotics:

$$ - \ln \epsilon  \int_0^b  e^{-1/x} \sim  {\epsilon} +{\epsilon^{1/2}}+{\epsilon^{1/3}}+\dots+{\epsilon^{1/N}} $$

Comment: There seems to be some error: $ f(\frac{-1}{\ln ( \epsilon^{1/r})})=\epsilon^{1/r}$.

Comment: @leonbloy fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approximation is (now) fine. The next-order correction should take into account the continuity correction in the integral.

Notice first that, using [the trapezoid rule](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/approximatingdefintegrals.aspx), the last term in the sum should be divided by two. (The first term does not matter, because the function starts at zero).

But notice also that, assuming $\epsilon, b$ are given, $-b \ln \epsilon$ is not an integer in general. Then, the last index of the sum is actually given by a rounding to the nearest integer  $ N = \lfloor N' \rceil = \lfloor  -b \ln \epsilon\rceil$.

Let $d = N - N'$, with $-\frac12 \le d \le \frac12$.

Then the integral is better approximated by

$$ \int_0^b  e^{-1/x} dx \approx \frac{-1}{\ln \epsilon} \left( \epsilon + \epsilon^{1/2} + \epsilon^{1/N}\right)- \frac{-1}{\ln \epsilon} \epsilon^{1/N}(d+1/2) \tag2$$

Or

$$\left( \epsilon + \epsilon^{1/2} + \epsilon^{1/N}\right) \approx -\ln \epsilon \int_0^b  e^{-1/x} dx - \epsilon^{1/N}(d+1/2) \tag 2$$

The graph compares the approximation in $(2)$ for $b=5$ (yellow line the zero order approximation; the red line, the corrected one, is indistinguishable from the exact integral value: $2.87100322120604$). The abscisa corresponds to $1/\epsilon$; in that range of values we get $N=37,38,39$.

[image]